# Extract properties from an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array as follows -

```
const options = [{text:'A', _id: '5trgh'}, {text:'B', _id: '5vjds'}, {text:'C', _id: '5njkn'}];
```

I want to extract the value of text based on _id. If I have just one _id, I can do it easily using filter as below -

```
const filteredText = options.filter(k => k._id == '5trgh'); // outputs A
```

I want to know what if I have multiple id's at once like 5trgh & 5vjds and I want to output A & B with filtered text.

Comment: Just change the comparison maybe?

Comment: `Array.filter()` returns an array with the results (even with a single result, it's an array of length 1, not a single value), so you'd have to figure out where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array and store the ids which you want to filter. Then use array filter and use `includes` to filter out the object whose id is in the `ids` array

```js
const ids = ['5trgh', '5njkn']
const options = [{
  text: 'A',
  _id: '5trgh'
}, {
  text: 'B',
  _id: '5vjds'
}, {
  text: 'C',
  _id: '5njkn'
}];

const filterArry = options.filter(item => ids.includes(item._id));
console.log(filterArry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```js
const options = [{text:'A', _id: '5trgh'}, {text:'B', _id: '5vjds'}, {text:'C', _id: '5njkn'}];

const IDs = options.map(item => item._id); // from this you could create buttons for example

IDs.forEach(id =>  console.log(id, options.filter(k => k._id == id)));
```